# EditContext OnFieldChanged reporting wrong return type

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, eventhandler

I have the 3 methods below in a razor file

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        EditContext = new EditContext(_projectModel);
        EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
    }
    
    
    private async Task EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await SetOkDisabledStatus();
    }
```

This method is an async method and I have to await it anywhere it is been called

```
    private async Task SetOkDisabledStatus()
    {
        if (EditContext.Validate())
        {
            OkayDisabled = null;
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Animate");
        }
        else
        {
            OkayDisabled = "disabled";
        }
    }
```

I am using the EditContext for validation in a Blazor server application.

I have been getting the error message  on this line below  in the OnInitializedAsync() method and not sure how to proceed with it.

```
    EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
```

Error Message:

Task MyProject.EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object, FieldChangedEventArgs)'
has the wrong return type.

Expected a method with void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object?, FieldChangedEventArgs e)

Please note that I am using sonarqube to check all my code.

Comment: Please, model your code after this code snippet: protected override void OnInitialized()  {  EditContext = new EditContext(Model); 
            EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
            base.OnInitialized();
        }

Comment: private void SetSaveDisabledStatus(FieldChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Each time a field changes this code is executed. EditContext.Validate() returns true if  validation succeeded; that is, both fields pass validation, in which case we assign the value null  to the property Disabled, and thus enabling the Save button.
            if (EditContext.Validate())  {  Disabled = null;   }
            else   {  Disabled = "disabled";  } }

Comment: Also, I don't think it's a good idea to use JSInterop. I would use CSS

Answer (score 3):

Generated Blazor eventhandlers (like `@onclick="..."`) are flexible about return type and parameters but `EditContext.OnFieldChanged` is not, it has a fixed delegate type.

Make the following change:

```
//private async Task EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
  private async void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     await SetOkDisabledStatus();
     StateHasChanged();  // make sure OkayDisabled takes effect
  }
```

On another note, you can probably make OkayDisabled a boolean and use `disabled="@OkayDisabled"` where you need it.
Blazor makes the `disabled` attribute disappear when you assign it with `false`.

---

Alternative: keep the validation synchronous. That might prevent some  problems as @Mister Magoo points out. And then let only the Animation run async.

```
private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
{
   SetOkDisabledStatus();  
}

private void SetOkDisabledStatus()
{
    if (EditContext.Validate())
    {
        OkayDisabled = null; 
        _ = JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Animate");  // no await, on purpose
    }
    else
    {
        OkayDisabled = "disabled";
    }
}
```

StateHasChanged() should not be needed in this scenario.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You can't use async void... It should be: private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
        {}

Comment: Also, the StateHasChanged method should not be used.

Comment: I hit this same problem and in my `OnFieldChanged` I have to call an `EventCallback`. And that only has `InvokeAsync()`. In practice the method(s) it is calling in my code are all synchronous (mostly assigning values). But it's an `InvokeAsync()` to call that synchronous method.

Comment: Yes, OnFieldChanged  is a 'normal' C# event and that is what the `async void` kludge was invented for. As long as your're aware that it is fire-and-forget and you don't have control over who finishes first it is workable.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign an async lambda to the event handler, like this:

```cs
EditContext.OnFieldChanged += 
  async (sender,args) => await EditContext_OnFieldChanged(sender,args);
```

But, you should be aware that the EditContext/Form will not `await` your task. Anything you do in that async task will be out of sync with the editcontext.

You should probably include a cancellation token in your async code as well, so that multiple changes to a field do not fire multiple validation tasks at the same time.

Async validation is hard - make sure you test every possible scenario.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the lambda is an `async void`, that's not so easy to see. You're right about async validation being hard.

Comment: @HenkHolterman  Nice comment - that's not something that had occurred to me, but makes sense - do you have any references for that?

Comment: Don't know about a specific reference but the compiler will infer `void`, not `Task`, for the return type and then you aply the `async` modifier. OnFieldChanged  cannot accept a Task method.